# Why does Thread.Sleep stacks up?

Tags: c#

I have a button which activates a timer for one tick. I want to hide my form, pause the form for 5.5s and then show it again.
What I have noticed is that if I press the button the first time after I started the application Thread.Sleep is 5.5s but if I press it again it sleeps for 11 seconds. After I pressed it a third time it sleeps for 16 seconds and so on...

This is really wierd for me and I'm not sure why it behaves that way.
Someone has an idea?

Note: Thread.Sleep is desperately needed for my application.

```cs
    using System.Threading;

    private void Btn_Abwesend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
            timer.Tick += timer1_Tick_1;
            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Start();
        }

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Thread.Sleep(5500);
            this.Show();
            timer.Stop();
        }
```

Comment: On each click of the button, you are adding a *new* Tick handler. The first time there's one, so you wait 5.5 seconds. The second time there is now two, so it's doubled, and so on. Move the first line of your click event outside (into the form's constructor most likely)

Comment: Kinda tangential, but: don't call `Thread.Sleep`. Ever ("well hardly everrrrrrr"). That isn't the right way of suspending a UI.

Comment: The Tick event subscription belongs in the constructor so it is only ever done once.  Put it after the InitializeComponent() call.  Or just drop a Timer with the designer onto the form so it is all automagic, also ensures the timer get stopped and disposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't unsubscribe from `Timer.Tick` event anywhere, so by pressing the button every time you add an additional handler in this line `timer.Tick += timer1_Tick_1;`. You should use `timer.Tick -= timer1_Tick_1;` somewhere in your code

Answer (score 4):

It is delegate subscriptions that stack up, i.e. this

```cs
timer.Tick += timer1_Tick_1;
```

Every time you do that, it **adds** a handler. The fact that the same target instance/method are added each time doesn't matter: it will get invoked multiple times. Only do that once, basically.